# monitoring the file in linux for special purpose，using sound or other effective method in Intranet

Tags: linux, redhat

There is a file like  SPRD130930.61 created by a process everyday in directory of /home/history，among them，’130930‘ stands for 2013 year 9 month 30 day，The rest is stable.And the file automaticcally Refresh every minute.

Now，I want to monitor it to watch whether it refresh every minute. If don't，it leads to audible alarm or msg to telphone or other effective method. How can I do this？

Answer (score 0):

Use `inotify`. See `man inotify`.

For shell scripts you can install package `inotify-tools`.

Simple command:

```
inotifywait -m /dev/null
```

See `man inotifywait`, `man inotifywatch`.

Comment: do  you  have other suggestions for this ？ i want  to catch  problem happening  in time  wherever  i am